# Type inference behaves differently for similar cases

Tags: dart, type-inference

Running the following code (Dart 2.3) throws the exception:
`type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<bool>'`

```dart
bar() => 0;
foo() => [bar()];

main() {
  var l = [1, 2, 3];
  l = foo();
}
```

However, this slightly altered example runs correctly:

```dart
main() {
  bar() => 0;
  var l = [1, 2, 3];
  l = [bar()];
}
```

As does this:

```dart
main() {
  bar() => 0;
  foo() => [bar()];
  var l = [1, 2, 3];
  l = foo();
}
```

What is it about Dart's type inference algorithm that makes these cases behave differently? Seems like the types of the functions `foo` and `bar` should be pretty easy to infer, since they always return the same value. It also isn't obvious to me why moving around the site of the function declaration would change type inference in these cases.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaf Petersen explains it in a comment to [dart-lang/sdk issue #33137: Type inference of function return value](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33137):

> This is by design. We do infer return types of non-recursive *local*
>   functions (functions declared inside of the scope of another function
>   or method), but for top level functions and methods, we do not infer
>   return types (except via override inference). The reasons are as
>   follows:
>
> - Methods and top level functions are usually part of the API of a program, and it's valuable to be able to quickly read off the API of a
>     piece of code. Doing method body based return type inference means
>     that understanding the signature of the API requires reading through
>     the method body.
> - Methods and top level functions can be arbitrarily mutually recursive, which makes the inference problem much harder and more
>     expensive.
>
> For primarily these reasons, we do not infer return types for top level functions and methods. Leaving off the return type is just another way of saying `dynamic`.

If you set

```
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-dynamic: false
```

in your `analysis_options.yaml` file, then `dartanalyzer` will generate errors when top-level functions have an implicit `dynamic` return type:

```
  error • Missing return type for 'bar' at example.dart:1:1 • strong_mode_implicit_dynamic_return
  error • Missing return type for 'foo' at example.dart:2:1 • strong_mode_implicit_dynamic_return
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like nested functions are treated differently than top-level functions. <s>It is probably a bug.</s> I get the following from Dartpad on Dart 2.3.1.

```
foo() => 0;
bar() => [foo()];

main() {
  baz() => 0;
  qux() => [baz()];
  print(foo.runtimeType);
  print(bar.runtimeType);
  print(baz.runtimeType);
  print(qux.runtimeType);
}

// () => dynamic
// () => dynamic
// () => int
// () => List<int>
```

Explanation [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/373):

> This is expected behavior.
>   Local functions use type inference to deduce their return type, but top-level/class-level functions do not.
>
> The primary reason for the distinction is that top-level and class level functions exist at the same level as type declarations. Solving cyclic dependencies between types and functions gets even harder if we have to also analyze function bodies at a time where we don't even know the signature of classes yet.
>
> When top-level inference has completed, we do know the type hierarchies, and where top-level functions are unordered, they can refer to each other in arbitrary ways, local functions are linear and can only depend on global functions or prior local functions. That means that we can analyze the function body locally to find the return type, without needing to look at anything except the body itself, and things we have already analyzed.